# input value in modal popup disappears, with input jquery value from button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I need help, I think this problem is really beyond my control, because I believe I have entered the code correctly.

in the case, I use **datatable**, then from the datatable there is a **button to send the value** into **script**, then the value sent to script is **forwarded to the Input Form** on the **Modal Popup**, what I am confused about is when in the browser view the data will successfully appear on the Input Form, but on the responsive (mobile) datatable display the data cannot be displayed and my Input Form is empty

very grateful if anyone can help, thank you very much

this is what i wrote

```js
<script>
  $('.data_send').on('click',function(){
    var data_1 = $(this).data('data_1');
    var data_2 = $(this).data('data_2');
    var data_3 = $(this).data('data_3');
    $('#input_1').val(data_1);
    $('#input_2').val(data_2);
    $('#input_3').val(data_3);
    $('#form_send_3').attr('action',"/pegawai/edit_akun/" + data_1);
  });
</script>
```

```html
<button type="button" 
  class="btn btn-sm btn-link data_send" 
  style="color: red;" 
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#modal_konfirmasi" 
  data-data_1="{{$p->id_peg}}" 
  data-data_2="{{$p->peg_nama}}"
  data-data_3="{{$p->peg_nip}}"
  >
  <i class="fa fa-lg uil uil-trash-alt" ></i>
</button>
            
            
 


<div class="modal fade" id="modal_konfirmasi" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
      <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="modal-header bg-red" >
          <div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="margin-top: -0.5vh; margin-bottom: -1vh;">
            <h5>Konfirmasi</h5>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >
          <h6>Yakin ingin menghapus data pegawai:</h6>
            <input id="input_a1" type="text" class="text-center form-control form-control-sm bg-red" >
            <input id="input_a2" type="text" class="text-center form-control form-control-sm bg-red" >
          <p> Aksi tidak dapat di urungkan, dan data tidak dapat dipulihkan</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" >
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" >Batal</button>
          <form id="form_send_1" role="form" method="post">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" hidden name="nama" value="{{$p->peg_nama}}" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" >Hapus</i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[This image when popup in mobile view - value not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzg5p.png)
[And this image when popup in browser view - value appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umlYk.png)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap5/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap5/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" ></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('.data_send').on('click',function(){
                var data_1 = $(this).data('data_1');
                var data_2 = $(this).data('data_2');
                var data_3 = $(this).data('data_3');
                $('#input_1').val(data_1);
                $('#input_2').val(data_2);
                $('#input_3').val(data_3);
                $('#form_send_3').attr('action',"/pegawai/edit_akun/" + data_1);
            })
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-link data_send"
        style="color: red;"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#modal_edit"
        data-data_1="D1"
        data-data_2="D2"
        data-data_3="D3"
>
    Button
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="modal_edit" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header bg-success" >
                <div class="modal-tittle" style="margin-top: -0.5vh; margin-bottom: -1vh;" >
                    <h5>Edit Pegawai</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
                <h6>Edit Akun</h6>
                <form id="form_send_3" role="form" method="post" action="">
                    @csrf
                    <input id="input_1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Penulisan tanpa spasi" name="id" >
                    <input id="input_2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Penulisan tanpa spasi" name="nama_old" >
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col col-4" >Email</div>
                        <div class="col col-8" >
                            <input id="input_3" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;" placeholder="email" required name="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col col-4" >Password</div>
                        <div class="col col-8" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;" placeholder="password" required minlength="8" name="password" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="text-end" >
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Perbarui Password" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

your code had some minor issues...

```
data-bs-target="#modal_edit"
```

1: was not matching model ID
2: the script should be in document.ready function

I have removed hidden form fields just for testing and in button hardcoded values you can run and see code ...
I have tested it in window mode and mobile mode both working fine...
If you are facing an issue on some specific device then explain it also.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it seems I entered the code incorrectly in the post above, in my code the modal has the id "modal_confirmation" not modal_edit

i do have 2 models in my code.

but the problem is still, your answer changing the modal id didn't solve my problem, because when in the mobile view the value still doesn't appear, it's like the script for the mobile view doesn't run on the datatable

thanks to you, is there any other way for this

Comment: try to open the mobile view for the first time, or if you are already in mobile view try to refresh the page, I found a problem when the view is opened in the mobile view directly, if I open the view in the browser view and change it to mobile without refresh, the value will appear.

Comment: The issue is not the ID. I have just told you it was mismatched you can enter any id you want.

Comment: @Katalina I have tested this code on chrome browser latest both in mobile you and PC view... But didn't faced any issue. I'll also try this again by your prescribed method.

Comment: Can you explain more about in what browser, what system and with what settings you are running this.  Maybe have problem with that specific browser or settings.